# Remove URL trailing slashes in .htaccess but keep if query string is present

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I use this rule to remove trailing slash in URL:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

But this also redirects URLs with query string.

So it redirects :

```
http://www.example.com/something/?q=text
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/something?q=text
```

I need to keep URL unchanged if query string is present

Answer (score 3):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. This doesn't seem to be negative condition. I need something like this just negative. So if query string doesn't exist then rewrite it. If it does then don't rewrite

Comment: That is exactly it does. If query string exists then don't redirect. You probably didn't pay attention to `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$` which means execute this rule if query string doesn't exist. You should test it in a new browser.